# How do I delete an object, when something hits it?

Tags: python, tkinter

This was in reference to a game I was creating. It's a simple game where if the ball hits the block, the block should disappear. If I did something like this:

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self,canvas,color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,110,20,fill=color )
```

and then:

```
def hit_block(self,pos):
    block_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.block.id)
    List = [block_pos]
    for i in List:
        if pos[0] >= i[0] and pos[2] <= i[2]:
            if pos[1] >= i[1] and pos[1] <= i[3]:
                canvas.delete(block.id)
                self.score()
                global a
                a += 1
                return True
    return False
```

The block doesn't get deleted. 
So what do you have to do to delete the block when the ball hits it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't work"*? Errors? Unexpected behaviour? What are you using to make the UI?

Comment: I'm using python canvas. By doesn't work, I mean that nothing happens. The ball bounces off, like it's supposed to, but the block is still there. It doesn't get deleted.

Comment: Do you mean the `tkinter Canvas`? What do you `import`? You may need to `delete(block)` rather than `delete(block.id)`.

Comment: Yes, Tkinter Canvas. Sorry about that. The thing is, I created several blocks in the Block class, using self.id1, self.id2, etc. But I tried using delete(block) and that isn't working either. I think it has to do with itemconfig and putting a tag, but I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`canvas.delete(block.id)` absolutely will work if `block.id` is a valid id that represents an object on the canvas. If it's not working, than `block.id` likely isn't what you think it is.

The problem in your code is that you were using `canvas.delete` rather than `self.canvas.delete`, and `block.id` rather than `self.block.id`

Comment: Thanks, the problem I was getting, is I had to specify self. I was supposed to write canvas.delete(self.block.id) since I was in the Ball class.